# AFJSONRequestOperation not working (postpath works)

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afjsonrequestoperation

I am trying to post a JSON using AFNetworking.

Here's the code that im using:

```
+ (RESTAPI *)sharedClient
{
    static RESTAPI *_sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        _sharedClient = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mybaseurl.com"]];
    });

    return _sharedClient;
}

- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    [self setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
    [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
    [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
    [self setAllowsInvalidSSLCertificate:YES];

    return self;
}
```

The following code does not works. Everytime i try i get the following error:

**The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)**

```
// this code does not works
// 
- (void)loginNOTWORKING
{
    RESTAPI *client = [RESTAPI sharedClient];

    [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] setEnabled:YES];
    [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] incrementActivityCount];

    NSDictionary *parameter = @{@"tgout": @"1",
                                @"tgin": @2,
                                @"username": @"foo",
                                @"password":@"bar"};
    NSURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/login" parameters:parameter];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        // code for successful return goes here
        [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] decrementActivityCount];
        NSLog(@"THIS IS NEVER CALLED: %@", JSON);
        // do something with return data
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        // code for failed request goes here
        [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] decrementActivityCount];
        NSLog(@"SAD, VERY SAD: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        // do something on failure
    }];

    [operation start];
}
```

This code works:

```
// this code WORKS
- (void)loginWORKING
{
    RESTAPI *client = [RESTAPI sharedClient];

    [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] setEnabled:YES];
    [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] incrementActivityCount];

    NSDictionary *parameter = @{@"tgout": @"1",
                                @"tgin": @2,
                                @"username": @"foo",
                                @"password":@"bar"};

    [client postPath:@"/login" parameters:parameter success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        // Print the response body in text
        NSLog(@"IT WORKS: %@",responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }];
}
```

Why the first login method does not works? What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try by replacing

```
NSURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/login" parameters:parameter];
```

with

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"/*HERE THE URL STRING TO CALL*/"]]
```

Comment: Same problem. Could it be a problem on my web server?

Comment: Yeah. It's like this:

`NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mybaseurl.com/login"]];`

Comment: have a look to this link, maybe it will help you. http://samwize.com/2012/10/25/simple-get-post-afnetworking/

Answer (score 0):

You can find the error -1012 in file `CFNetworkErrors.h`:

```
kCFURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication = -1012
"The connection failed because the user cancelled required authentication."
```

I guess, there is an issue with your authentication. The error description is possibly misleading with regard to "the user"  -  it is actually a delegate method that gets invoked which cancels the authentication, or the authentication simply fails.

This of course can be caused by not properly serializing the parameters. I would suggest to use a lower level API, create the request manually, encode the JSON manually with `NSJSONSerialization`, and set the body data and the URL of the request. IMHO, this is certainly more readable code, and likely requires less code.